# Looking for properties resolver for .properties and .y(a)ml files in Kotlin/Java like in Spring

Tags: java, spring, kotlin, properties

I am developing library in Kotlin and now I am looking for properties resolver library like Spring have, but don't want to use Spring library directly.

I don't want library to be dependent on Spring jars.

Do you know some alternatives?

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on Stack Overflow please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) and [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and if not already done, [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: @Bsquare if you don’t like my question, press close button, man.

Answer (score 0):

You want to read yaml and properties files?

dependencies:

```
compile "com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin:${jacksonVersion}"
compile "com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-yaml:${jacksonVersion}"
compile "com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-properties:${jacksonVersion}"
```

code:

```
// Read ObjectMapper docs to learn about the different config options
val mapper = ObjectMapper(YAMLFactory()).registerKotlinModule()//...
val stream = FileInputStream(File(filename))
mapper.readValue<MyProperties>(stream)
```